# How does Batman avoid killing people?

Tags: dc, batman

He throws people off of high places, uses a sharp Batarang and plain beats people up to the point where they'd most likely be dead afterwards.

Is there an in-universe (or out-of-universe) explanation of **how** Batman manages to avoid killing his adversaries who seem to be extremely likely to be killed by his actions?

Is that that he's so intelligent he knows exactly how much someone can take? If that's the case, surely no one can take being thrown off a tall building.

Comment: He does kill people, just not recently; http://i.newsarama.com/images/i/000/119/898/i300/batman-kills-mad-monk.jpg, http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-I4j0zhr-fxg/TxmwA8_a2lI/AAAAAAAAG0I/nwI1M_Stmmc/s1600/batman-kills2-Batman01.gif

Comment: Sorry, that's very small resolution and I can't read it. Which comic is that from, anyway?

Comment: It was from "Batman and the Mad Monk". This article might also be of interest - http://www.cracked.com/article_20111_the-6-most-brutal-murders-committed-by-batman.html

Comment: Why the DV and VTC? Even if he killed before, the "no killing" is definitely a well known and important part of the large chunk of Bat-universe (less so than Superman, admittedly)

Comment: A problem raised by [Tim Absath, of `cad-comic.com` (formerly 'ctrl-alt-delete')](http://www.cad-comic.com/cad/20090831).

Comment: Even with the amendments, this is still way too broad (even ignoring the fact that the question is plain wrong, he does kill people, relatively regularly)

Comment: Yes, but when he does is it not intentional? Surely when beating up common crooks he'd prefer to avoid killing them by throwing them off skyscrapers when he could just knock them out. The question was, when using this heavy handed approach, if he doesn't mean to outright kill then how does he make sure of that? Perhaps the question would be better focussed on Batman's application of non-lethal force and how successful it is. It would also be worth mentioning whether he intends to kill or not.

Comment: I think that Batman has pointed to other members of the batfamily who he himself has trained that it takes more control, discipline and skill to be able to fight the way they do without seriously hurting or killing someone. To a certain point, Batman refrains himself of using deadly force. Certainly he takes his risks, but as you pointed he tries not give someone more than what they can take. In the dark knight, I guess he calculated that that fall (and the way he pushed him) would seriously hurt Maroni, but not kill him.

Comment: First useful answer, thanks very much +1.